# Data.table with duplicate entries but all columns dont match, are empty, or have correctiona

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataset with duplicate entries. They were likely due to data errors. After an entry is wrong, its corrected with ANOTHER entry. How would one go about using this data. As a toy example:

```
dt1 <- data.table(
    id = c('a','','a','b','','b','c','','c'), 
    v1 =c('a','a','a','b','b','','c','','c'), 
    v2 =c('a','a','a','b','','b','','','c'), 
    v3 =c('a','a','a','','b','','','c',''), 
    v4 =c('','a','','b','','','c','','c'), 
    v5 =c('a','','a','','','b','','','c'), 
    v6 =c('','a','','','b','b','c','c','c')
    )
```

What I would like:

```
dt1 <- data.table(
    id =c('a','b','c'),
    v1 =c('a','b','c'),
    v2 =c('a','b','c'),
    v3 =c('a','b','c'),
    v4 =c('a','b','c'),
    v5 =c('a','b','c'),
    v6 =c('a','b','c'),
    )
```

In the above example, think of id representing the id variable and v1-v6 are filled in with random information

Comment: (1) Please test your code before asking the question, your second code block is a syntax error (extra comma). (2) It's easy to try to solve this (`dt1[, lapply(.SD, function(Z) Filter(nzchar, unique(Z)))]`) but that is fragile to the assumption that all columns must have the same number of unique values, a critical assumption that you have not stated. Additionally, (3) you say that `id` is an id variable but it looks identical (and identically incorrect) to the data columns. Is there a premise of "ID" in this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `tidyverse`. The idea is first replace "" with `NA`, use `fill` to impute the `id` column, `group_by` the `id`, and `summarize` each column to keep information.

It is not clear what your "random information" looks like, and how do you want to summarize the information. Here, I am assuming that you want to keep the first non-NA value in each `id` and each column. This is what `~first(.x[!is.na(.x)]))` is trying to achieve. If you have other ways to summarize the data, provide your function in this location.

```
library(tidyverse)

dt1[dt1 == ""] <- NA

dt1_2 <- dt1 %>%
  fill(id, .direction = "downup") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(across(.fns = ~first(.x[!is.na(.x)]))) %>%
  ungroup()

dt1_2
# # A tibble: 3 x 7
#   id    v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    v6   
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 a     a     a     a     a     a     a    
# 2 b     b     b     b     b     b     b    
# 3 c     c     c     c     c     c     c
```

**Update**

Below code shows how to use tow `across` to apply different functions to different groups of columns.

```
dt1_2 <- dt1 %>%
  fill(id, .direction = "downup") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(across(v1:v4, .fns = ~first(.x[!is.na(.x)])),
            across(v5:v6, .fns = ~last(.x[!is.na(.x)]))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

**Update2**

Here is an updated solution, which deals with a situation when no any duplicates contain non-NA values.

```
dt2 <- data.table(
  id = c('a','','a','b','','b','c','','c'), 
  v1 =c('a','a','a','b','b','','c','','c'), 
  v2 =c('a','a','a','b','','b','','',''), 
  v3 =c('a','a','a','','b','','','c',''), 
  v4 =c('','a','','b','','','c','','c'), 
  v5 =c('a','','a','','','b','','','c'), 
  v6 =c('','a','','','b','b','c','c','c')
)

dt2[dt2 == ""] <- NA

fill_fun <- function(x, fun){
  if (all(is.na(x))){
    result <- NA
  } else {
    result <- fun(x[!is.na(x)])
  }
  return(result)
}


dt2_2 <- dt2 %>%
  fill(id, .direction = "downup") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(across(v1:v4, .fns = ~fill_fun(.x, fun = first)),
            across(v5:v6, .fns = ~fill_fun(.x, fun = last))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: This was really helpful!! I have a question with regards to keeping the first non-NA value of each id:

Suppose that there existed a column v7 and v8 that identified the latest version of the entry. Let's suppose v7 is year and v8 is month, something that has some order. Ok, then let's assume the same problem of duplicates even with a given v7 and v8--BUT now there's more precision because you know duplicates should at least be the latest entry. How does your "first" function deal with that? Is there a better way than just "~first(.x[!is.na(.x)]))"

Comment: @econfin Please see my update.

Comment: thanks for the update. One last issue--if some new id d simply has NA for column v2 across all duplicates, how will your function deal with that?

Comment: @econfin you mean there are no any non-NA values in v2?

Comment: exactly, so  id **'a'**, **'b'**, and **'c'** have a duplicate entry where v2 is filled in with some non-NA value. But for id **'d'**, non of the duplicates have a non-NA value. If **'d'** had five duplicates non of them have a non-NA v2. 

BUT it looks like you already did the update!!! you're amazing!!